# Azure Mobile Services: {System.TypeLoadException} = {"Entry point was not found.":""}

Tags: azure, windows-8, azure-mobile-services, entrypointnotfoundexcept

Actually I'm having some problems with the Azure Mobile Services. Because I'm getting the error "{System.TypeLoadException} = {"Entry point was not found.":""}", when I try to convert the table to a collection view. Everytime I'm getting a empty list back with this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I find the solve of problem  [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/azuremobile/thread/34c5afce-ca4a-4f10-844b-826777c74b27). In two words: 

Because collectionView fetch data asynchronously, we need work with our collection, when she loaded at all.  For e.g:

`items = todoTable.ToCollectionView();` 

`items.CollectionChanged += items_CollectionChanged;`

`void items_CollectionChanged(object sender,           System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    
    {
            if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            {
                int n = items.Count;
            }
        }`


I used this Microsoft [example](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-dotnet)